# Is there any sleep/wait/delay function in After Effects?

Tags: after-effects

I'm trying to code a script that will write `final_text` into a `Text Layer`, letter by letter, waiting a small time between each letter being written. Is there any way to do it?

```
final_text = '#a80030';
characters = '';
for(i = 0; i < final_text.length; i++){
    characters += final_text[i];
    text.sourceText +=  characters;
    #sleep for 500ms
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're confusing scripts and expressions. `$.sleep` is a method of the global object in scripting, but not in expressions. And it would make no sense to use it in an expression because it would just make the expression take longer to calculate. You need to [read the manual](https://helpx.adobe.com/after-effects/how-to/creating-animating-text.html).

TL;DR:
Create a text layer with the final text in it. You could also use an expression on the text source property of the layer. Apply an opacity text animator (you did read the manual didn't you?) to the layer. Turn the opacity of the animator to zero. add an expression selector and delete the normal selector.

[image]

Apply this expression to the selector:

```
(time*2 < textIndex)? 100 : 0
```

This uses the characters index to compare to the current time * 2 (time is measured in seconds), so every 500ms the index of the letters that are set to zero opacity (100% selected) will increment.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is the `$.sleep()` method.
So all you need to do is

```js
$.sleep(500);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but unfortunately I've already tried this and I got the following error `Error: TypeError: $.sleep is not a function`

Comment: That's strange. When I try it here in my After Effects, it works. Did you by any chance overwrite the `$` helper object earlier in the script? Or used a third party library that does?

Comment: nope, I've just `ALT+CLICK` over the watch of `Source text layer` and wrote in there the script

Comment: Ah, as the question was tagged with ExtendScript originally, I didn't know you are trying to write an expression. That's something different than a script and as you just have pointed out, the `$.sleep` method won't work in this case. I think stib's answer should help you out in this case.